# Pass a query url param inside a graphql query (Next js)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql

I'm trying to get a content by the slug param in the url inside a next js app. When using getServerSideProps, I can pass a context.query.id, but here I'm trying to use getStaticProps. This is what I have so far:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const apolloClient = initializeApollo();
  const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
    query: SLUG_QUERY,
  });

  return addApolloState(apolloClient, {
    props: {
      data,
    },
    revalidate: 60,
  });
}

const SLUG_QUERY = gql`
  query ($id: String!) {
    postCollection(slug: { eq: $id }) {
      items {
        title
        shortDescription
        heroImg {
          url
        }
        createdAt
        slug
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

I'm struggling to understand How can I pass the conbtext.query.id as a  parameter in the gql query.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Where is the `$id` coming from? Are you using this in combination with `getStaticPaths`? Is this a dynamic page?

Comment: yeah this is a [id].tsx file, and get static path is mapping   const paths = data.postCollection.items.map((post) => ({
    params: { id: post.slug },
  }))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass context into your `getStaticProps` function

```js
export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
```

then move your query inside the `getStaticProps` to use it

```js
postCollection(slug: { eq: $context.params.id }) {
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to keep your query outside of the function (if you are reusing it elsewhere for example), then just wrap it in a function that takes the id as a parameter

```js
const getPostCollectionQuery = (id) => {
  const SLUG_QUERY = gql`
    query ($id: String!) {
      postCollection(slug: { eq: $id }) {
        items {
          title
          shortDescription
          heroImg {
            url
          }
          createdAt
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  return SLUG_QUERY;
};
```

and then you can call that from your `getStaticProps` function

```js
const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
  query: getPostCollectionQuery(context.params.id),
});
```

Comment: but the gql literal query is outside the getStaticProps, I've tried passing it down but doesn't work:  export const SLUG_QUERY = (id) => gql`
query($id: String!) {
  postCollection(slug: { eq: $id }){
    items{
      title,
      shortDescription,
      heroImg{
        url
      }
      createdAt,
      slug
    }
  }
}
`;

Comment: export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const apolloClient = initializeApollo();
  const { data } = await apolloClient.query({
    query: SLUG_QUERY(context.params.id)
  });

Comment: @RobertoFosso I missed the fact that you had defined the query outside the function. I've updated my answer. Either move the query inside the function or wrap the query in a helper function

Comment: Sorry to come back on this, but the id param after the function declaration is grey out, and is not being passed inside the gql query. I'm getting now the error: ' Variable "$id" of required type "String!" was not provided.'